# Как определить позицию курсора в текстовом поле?

Tags: javascript

Есть длинный текст в textarea и курсор, который находится на какой-то позиции в тексте. Как мне определить позицию курсора?

Comment: https://webtips.dev/webtips/javascript/how-to-get-caret-position-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var txtArea = document.getElementById('txtArea');
    var caretPos =  getCursorPosition(txtArea);
    console.log(caretPos);
});

function getCursorPosition(txtArea) {
  return txtArea.selectionStart;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<button id="btn">Get cursor position</button>
```